# grep never returns anything unless I put a * or . on the end - why?

Tags: linux, grep

If I put a * or . on the end of a grep command, I will get results instantly. However, if I don't, the command never returns anything.

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me why, or direct me to a source that includes that information!  Looking online all, everything talks about searching FOR a period or asterisk in your search. Most examples don't include a * or ., and the ones that do don't tell me what they're actually doing.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an exact command line that exhibits the problem?

Comment: `man grep` on your terminal

Comment: Yes, I did.  Other answers explained that it was actually waiting for input/a pipe, which wasn't clear to me from the man page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a list of files to search, grep reads stdin by default. e.g.

```
$ grep -o a..
This appears to freeze, but is actually just waiting for input
app
ars
act
all
ait
^D
```

By the way, grep’s more useful cousin, ack, does what you’d expect. :)

Comment: Thanks!  I thought it was simply stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The last argument to grep is where to search - when you say * you indicate that everything in the current directory should be searched, when you say dot you also indicate the current directory. If you leave these off, then grep assumes that you are going to pass the text to search through via a pipe, so it is sitting and waiting for the text to arrive (ie for you to type it in)

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize it was waiting for input.